# Function returns value to console but not to file

Tags: function, powershell

Trying to write a function to create a new line to be added to a table for export. The following outputs the correct values to the console but the CSV is empty.

If I place the code to create `$newline` at various point in the script it works fine but not when I call it as a function.

```
    $report = @()

Function CreateNewLine
{
$lineproperties = @{
Cluster = $cluster
Node = $node
Database = $d.Name
LogCount = $logcount
LogPath = $p
}

$newline = New-Object PSObject -property $lineproperties
}

# Loop to create values for $cluster etc...

CreateNewLine
$report += $newline

# End loop

$report |  Export-CSV 'pathto file' -notype
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scope issue here. `$newline` has no context outside the function. Therefore you would just be adding $null to the `$report` array. Make the function return the value which can then be captured.

```
Function CreateNewLine
{
    $lineproperties = @{
        Cluster = $cluster
        Node = $node
        Database = $d.Name
        LogCount = $logcount
        LogPath = $p
    }

    New-Object PSObject -property $lineproperties
}

# Loop to create values for $cluster etc...

$report += CreateNewLine
```

The function should have access to those other variables as long as they are in the parent scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function `CreateNewLine` never returns a value. You need to do the following:

```
Function CreateNewLine
{
    $lineproperties = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Cluster = $cluster
        Node = $node
        Database = $d.Name
        LogCount = $logcount
        LogPath = $p
    }
    $lineProperties
}
```

Comment: If you are going to do that then you don't even need to bother with the variable assignment.

Comment: In this simplistic case, true, but I wanted to emphasize the part where the value wasn't being returned, since there may be other logic omitted for the question.

Comment: FYI You need to be sure you are using PowerShell 3.0 or higher for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object in much easier manner (as Matt said, this works in Powershell 3.0 and later):

```
Function CreateNewLine
{
  [pscustomobject]@{
  Cluster = $cluster
  Node = $node
  Database = "name"
  LogCount = $logcount
  LogPath = $p
  }
}
```

Then, in any place you want you can use this function:

```
$cluster = "cluster 1"
$report += createnewline

$cluster = "cluster 2"
$report += createnewline

$report |  Export-CSV 'pathto file' -notype
```

Comment: FYI You need to be sure you are using PowerShell 3.0 or higher for this to work.